# How to change VMware MAC address on host machine

Tags: windows-xp, networking, vmware-workstation

I found many pages that discuss changing the MAC address of the interface inside the VM (guest), I have not found any information for changing the virtual interfaces on the host machine.

VMware Workstation 6.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help: [Changing the MAC address of vmnet0 - vmnet9](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-9664)